# derivative of an implicit matrix function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let $\mathbf{V}$ be an $N \times N$ real symmetric (or complex Hermitian) positive definite matrix, such that $\mathrm{det}(\mathbf{V})=1$.

By means of the implicit function theorem, its first top-left entry $[V]_{1,1} \triangleq v_{11} $ can be expressed as:

- Real symmetric (positive definite) $\mathbf{V}$:
  \begin{equation*}
  [V]_{1,1} \triangleq v_{11} = g_\mathbb{R}(v_{1,2},\ldots,v_{N,N}),
  \end{equation*}
  where $v_{1,2},\ldots,v_{N,N}$ are the $N \times (N+1)/2-1$ entries of the upper triangular submatrix except $v_{11}$,
- Complex Hermitian (positive definite) $\mathbf{V}$:
  \begin{equation*}
  [V]_{1,1} \triangleq v_{11} = g_\mathbb{C}(v_{1,2},v_{2,1}\ldots,v_{N,N}),
  \end{equation*}
  where $v_{1,2},v_{2,1},\ldots,v_{N,N}$ are the $N^2 - 1$ entries of $\mathbf{V}$ except $v_{11}$,

and $g_{\mathbb{R}}$, $g_{\mathbb{C}}$ are differentiable functions (but I haven't its explicit expression).

How can I explicitly evaluate the following (column) vectors ?
\begin{equation*}
 \mathbf{s}_{\mathbb{C}} = \frac{\partial g([\mathbf{V}]_{2,1},\ldots,[\mathbf{V}]_{N,N})}{\partial \underline{\mathrm{vec}}(\mathbf{V})}
\end{equation*}
for $\mathbf{V} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$ (Hermitian positive definite) and where $\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{V}) \triangleq [v_{11},\underline{\mathrm{vec}}(\mathbf{V})^T]^T$ and

\begin{equation*}
 \mathbf{s}_{\mathbb{R}} = \frac{\partial g([\mathbf{V}]_{2,1},\ldots,[\mathbf{V}]_{N,N})}{\partial \underline{\mathrm{vech}}(\mathbf{V})}
\end{equation*}
for $\mathbf{V} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ (symmetric positive definite) and where $\mathrm{vech}(\mathbf{V}) \triangleq [v_{11},\underline{\mathrm{vech}}(\mathbf{V})^T]^T$ and $\mathrm{vech}$ is the (column-wise) vectorization of the upper triangular part of $\mathbf{V}$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\d{\lambda}\def\g{\gamma}
\def\u#1{\underline{#1}}
\def\e{\varepsilon}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\E{E_{\o\o}}
\def\M{M_{\o\o}}
\def\W{W_{\o\o}}
\def\V{V_{\o\o}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\vec#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\vech#1{\operatorname{vech}\LR{#1}}
\def\adj#1{\operatorname{adj}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\mc#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r|rrr}#1\end{array}\right]}
$Let $E_{ij}\in\bbR{N\times N}$ denote a standard basis matrix with the $(i,j)^{th}$ element equal to $\o$ and all others equal to $0$.
Similarly use $\e_k\in\bbR{N^2\times\o}$ to denote a standard basis vector whose $k^{th}$ element equals $\o$.

Let's also use a colon to denote the Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
This is also called the double-dot or double contraction product.

When applied to vectors $(n=N^2,\,m=\o)$ it reduces to the standard dot product.

When applied to square matrices $(n=N,\,m=N)$ the trace definition is convenient.

The function in question can be rewritten in a form which is easily differentiated.
$$\eqalign{
g &= \E:V \\
  &= \vec{\E}:\vec{V} \\
  &= {\e_{\o}}:v \\
dg &= {\e_{\o}}:dv \\
\grad{g}{v} &= {\e_{\o}} \\
}$$
In the symmetric case, let
$$\eqalign{
w &= \vech{V}, \quad
v &= \vec{V} &= Dw \\
}$$
where $D$ is the [Duplication matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplication_and_elimination_matrices#Elimination_matrix)

Then by a similar calculation
$$\eqalign{
g &= {\e_{\o}}:v \\
  &= {\e_{\o}}:Dw \\
  &= D^T{\e_{\o}}:w \\
dg &= D^T{\e_{\o}}:dw \\
\grad{g}{w} &= D^T{\e_{\o}} \qquad\qquad\qquad \\
}$$
which is just the first basis vector
for the *half-vec* space $\bbR{N(N+1)/2}$

### Update #1

The comments pointed out that underlined quantities explicitly *exclude* the $\V$ element, e.g.
$$\u{v}=\u{\rm vec}(V)$$
For these underlined `vec/vech` operators, both of the derivatives are **zero vectors** of dimensions $\,\bbR{N^2-\o}\,$ and $\,\bbR{N(N+\o)/2-\o}\,$ respectively.

### Update #2

Based on the comments, the intent of the question is to consider $\V$ as an implicit function of the remaining elements of $V$ based on the constraint $\,\det(V)=\o.\,$

The first step is to reverse the vectorizations and reconstitute the matrix. Since $(\o,\o)$ element is not part of the vectors, the respective `unvec` operators will set it to zero in the reconstituted matrix, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
&M = \u{\rm unvec}(\u{v}) = \u{\rm unvech}(\u{w}) \\
&\M = 0 \\
}$$
Calculate the inverse and determinant of this reconstituted matrix.
$$\eqalign{
W &= M^{-1}  \\
\d &= \det(M) \qiq \g=\det(W)=\d^{-1} \\
}$$
The remaining task is to calculate $\M$ such that the constraint $\d=\o$ is satisfied.

The [Jacobi formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula#Alternative_Derivation) tells us that
$$\eqalign{
 \d &= \det(M) \qiq d\d = \d W^T:dM \\
}$$
If the change $dM$ is restricted to its $(\o,\o)$ element then we are left with the scalar equation
$$\eqalign{
d\d &= \d \W\;d\M \\
}$$
The increment $d\d=(\o-\d)\,$ yields $\,(\d+d\d)=\o,\,$
which satisfies the constraint.

Therefore incrementing the $\M$ element by
$$\eqalign{
d\M &= \frac{\o-\d}{\d\W} \qiq V = M + \E\,d\M \\
}$$
will satisfy the constraint, assuming that neither
$\W$ nor $\d$ is equal to zero. For the proposed
${V},\,$ applying the [Matrix Determinant Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) will verify that indeed $\,\det({V})=\o$.

Now we can write an explicit expression for the $g$-function
$$\eqalign{
g = \V
  = \LR{\frac{\o-\d}{\d\W}} 
  = \LR{\frac{\det(W)-\o}{\E:W}} 
\\
}$$
which we can differentiate
$$\eqalign{
dg &= \LR{\frac{d\det(W)}{\E:W}}
  - \LR{\frac{\det(W)-\o}{(\E:W)^2}}\BR{\E:dW} \\
 &= \LR{\frac{\g M:dW}{\E:W}}
  - \LR{\frac{\g-\o}{(\E:W)^2}}\BR{\E:dW} \\
 &= \LR{\frac{(\E:W)\g M-(\g-\o)\E}{(\E:W)^2}}:dW \\
 &= \LR{\frac{(\g-\o)\E-\g\W M}{\W^2}}:W\,dM\,W \\
 &= W\LR{\frac{(\g-\o)\E-\g\W M}{\W^2}}W:dM \\
 &= \LR{\frac{(\g-\o)\LR{W\E W}-\g\W W}{\W^2}}:dM \\
 &=\u{\rm vec}\LR{\frac{(\g-\o)\LR{W\E W}-\g\W W}{\W^2}}:d\u{v} \\
\grad{g}{\u{v}}
 &=\u{\rm vec}\LR{\frac{(\g-\o)\LR{W\E W}-\g\W W}{\W^2}} \\
}$$
The Duplication matrix immediately yields the other derivative
$$\eqalign{
\grad{g}{\u{w}} &= \u{D}^T \LR{\grad{g}{\u{v}}} \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad \\
\\
}$$

---

**NB:** The following matrix removes the first element of
an $n$-vector
$$\eqalign{
R(n) = \m{ 0_{n-1} & I_{n-1}},
\quad {\rm e.g.}\;\; 
R(4) = \m{
0 & \o &  0 &  0 \\
0 &  0 & \o &  0 \\
0 &  0 &  0 & \o \\
} \in \bbR{3\times 4}
\\
}$$
For typing convenience, let $R=R\BR{N^2}$
and $Q=R\BR{N(N+\o)/2}$

This allows all of the *underlined* symbols to be
expressed in standard matrix notation
$$\eqalign{
\u{w} &= \u{\rm vech}(V) &= Q\;\vech{V} &= Qw \\
\u{v} &= \u{\rm vec}(V)  &= R\;\vec{V}  &= Rv \\
\u{D} &= RDQ^T \\
}$$
$$\eqalign{
M &= \u{\rm unvech}(\u{w}) &= {\rm unvech}(Q^T\u{w})\quad \\
  &= \u{\rm unvec}(\u{v})  &= {\rm unvec}(R^T\u{v}) \\
}$$

### Update #3

Exploiting the [block structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices) of the matrix to evaluate the determinant
yields an alternate expression for the $g$-function.
$$\eqalign{
V &= \mc{\V & x^T \\ x&Y} \;=\; V^T \\
\det(V) &= \LR{\V-x^TY^{-1}x} \det(Y) \;&\doteq\; \large\o \\
\V &= x^TY^{-1}x + \det(Y^{-1}) \;&\doteq\; g \\
}$$
If you differentiate this expression you will find
$$\eqalign{
dg
 &= 2Y^{-1}x:dx - Y^{-1}\LR{xx^T+\frac I{\det Y}}Y^{-1}:dY \\\\
   &= \mc{
  2Y^{-1}x \\
 -D^T\LR{Y\otimes Y}^{-1}\vec{xx^T+\frac I{\det Y}} \\
}:d\u{v} \\\\
\grad{g}{\u{v}}
   &= \mc{
  2Y^{-1}x \\
 -D^T\LR{Y\otimes Y}^{-1}\vec{xx^T+\frac I{\det Y}} \\
} \\\\
}$$
Note that
$$\eqalign{
{\rm vech}(V)
 = \mc{\V \\ x \\ {\rm vech}(Y)}
 = \mc{\V \\ x \\ y}
,\qquad
\u{v}
 = \u{\rm vech}(V)
 = \mc{x \\ y}
\\
}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I don’t understand how “my” $g$ function can be rewritten as “your” $g = E_{11}:V$. In fact, $g = E_{11}:V$ depends on $v_11$, while my version not. Moreover, the derivative has to be taken with respect to all the elements of $V$ expect $v_11$, as the notation $\bar{\mathrm{vec}}$ indicates…

Comment: @Vuk Of course your $g$-function depends on $V_{11}.\,$   _Every_  cofactor $C_{1n}$ which appears in the summation contains $V_{11}$ in its determinant definition. In fact, the $g$-function represents nothing more than $\,g=V_{11}\;$ written in a very obtuse fashion.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are right… I wrote the post because I needed to derive the implicit function $v_{11} = g(v_{12},…,v_{NN})$ obtained by imposing the constraint $\mathrm{det}(V)=1$ on $V$. But, as you said, the expression of the implicit function $g$ is wrong… When I solve for $v_{11}$ i have to consider the ones in the cofactors... I'll try...

Comment: @Vuk I think I understand the question now and have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry again for the confusion. I updated the question by removing the wrong expression of $g$. I'll think on your answer to see if I can use it to solve my problem ;)